# Android instant app: Strategy for splitting up single activity apps

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-instant-apps

I am currently investigating how we can get an instant app version of our app. 
The main issue/question i have is how we can split up the app into smaller chunks so we meet the requirements of the max 4MB limit for instant app modules.

Now our app is a single activity containing multiple fragment views.
Our main Activity and Application class is basically holding most of the app dependencies. The same goes for the app gradle file. There is no way i can reduce this to 4mb.

At this point i see no other option than to create an entirely new project containing multiple activities with parts of the original Activity. 
Problem is that the fragment views usually have a dependency with the original activity (since the activity is more or less a controller). So i need to modify those as well.

I am wondering if there is anybody out there dealing with the same challenge. Would like to hear what approach you take to solve this situation.

Comment: How big is your current APK? Where is most of the size being used? Is there any chance of removing some of the heavier libraries and/or resources for the Instant App only? If so, that would be a more straightforward approach to start with. If not, then you may indeed need to rearchitect your app structure to some extent.

Comment: The app is +- 10 mb in total. 
drawables together 4mb (i can probably reduce this by optimising images)
values 3mb ( translations for 25 languages and quite some layout files)
jar files 1mb (external libs for ads etc)
code 2mb

so i guess i need to look into the drawable and values files. But how would you split those. You have to use multiple activites in that case. they are all bundeled as resources.

Comment: @GillisHaasnoot there is no "quick and dirty" hack to solve your problem. You have to re-architect. If you have everything in fragments, it shouldn't take much to create a new module with a new activity that reuses these fragments. You can do it a bit at a time as well.

Comment: @GillisHaasnoot Can you include the info from your reply in your original question, I think that would make it clearer.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure there's a single strategy that will work for all apps. There are many factors to consider when choosing if or how to refactor your application (for Instant Apps or otherwise).

With that said, given the information you have provided, here is some general guidance.

**Option #1 - Reduce current APK down to 4MB or less**

Given your current APK is ~10MB and there is clearly some room for further size optimization, it might be possible to create an Instant App feature APK that is <=4MB. The [docs](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/reduce-apk-size.html) have some great info on reducing APK size but here are some suggestions that will likely give you the largest gains given the info you have provided. Note that you can structure your modules so that these changes only take affect on your compiled Instant App binary and not on your regular APK.

- drawable resources - remove multiple density buckets, keeping only one bucket (the Android system still scales assets automatically for other densities you don't include), you probably want to only keep `xhdpi` or maybe `xxhdpi`
- drawable resources - if there are any large drawables, see if you can remove them (eg. splash screen drawables -- splash screens are not needed for Instant Apps as the system shows one for you before the Instant App starts)
- drawable resources - with the drawables you have left, see if you can convert to [`webp`](https://developers.google.com/speed/webp/) format which is supported natively on all Instant App devices (for some graphics you can also look at using vector drawables)
- translation strings - can you remove some of these based on your largest markets? Instant Apps are also not launched in some countries yet (exactly list will be published soon hopefully) but if you have strings for India, Indonesia or Brazil (emerging markets) you can remove those for your Instant App
- layout files - if you have specific layout files that are particularly large in size, you may want to look into using newer layout managers such as [`ConstraintLayout`](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/index.html), this can help flatten and simplify your layouts (which is more performant) and potentially shrink size as well
- libraries and code - are there any libraries or sections of your code that may not pertain to the Instant App? if so, make sure you remove structure your modules so these are not included in the Instant App binary
- otherwise ensure you have [Proguard minify enabled](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code.html#shrink-resources) and [`shrinkResources`](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/reduce-apk-size.html#remove-unused) on as well

**Option #2 - Refactor your app**

If you don't think you can reduce your current APK down to 4MB or less, then the next step is to look at refactoring. How this is accomplished is largely dependent on your current codebase and the functions of your app. However, from a high level, you should identify any logical break points in the app that would line up nicely as key entry points for the Instant App. For example, a travel app may have separate entry points for its hotels, flights and car rentals experiences.

Otherwise most of the statements you made in your original questions sound right. You will need to break your app down from a single activity into a more modularized form.

> Problem is that the fragment views usually have a dependency with the
>   original activity (since the activity is more or less a controller).

You should usually avoid child fragments having heavy dependencies on their parent activities. They should be quite compartmentalized if possible. This might be a good first step to tackle.

Answer (score 0):

Despite what google advises I created an entire new project for the instant app. The whole process of refactoring an existing app into features and base projects is hard. I spend almost a month trying to get it done, but failed. I find the whole instant app structure way too over complicated and still don't understand it. 
Just copy and paste code between real app and instant app is way faster. In many cases the logic between the real app and the instant app is slightly different anyway.

Answer (score 0):

We had to do exactly this for a 200k+ lines of code project and our approach was to make a new activity only to be used by the instant app. We created this activity in the feature module.

Then we moved all fragments used by the feature to the feature model and use those fragments both in the instant app activity and the installed activity.

Then we hooked the feature activity up with the necessary callbacks.

If you want to exclude the feature activity in the installed app you can simply move that activity one more step up in the dependency chain but it didn't matter for us so we kept it in.

Pros: Saves a lot of time
Cons: Still a better design to have multiple activities.

Answer (score 0):

As the others already stated, you have to refactor your whole app. But what anybody has not written clearly is the following sentence.

Since you have multiple fragments in one activity this structure should offer to split the fragments into multiple activities. All those small enough form then your instant app.